# Interaction between Java and JavaScript?

Tags: java, javascript, google-maps

I now work with Google Map (which now I got it in .html file with JavaScript inside)
and now I've achieved many task I want in Java. Here is the problem.

Since my Google Map will have pin marker on the map, I need to, once it is clicked,
some variables or details from JavaScript(Aka. Google Map) will be sent to Java.

I would like to use those variables or details in Java to make more functions, but I'm not sure if is possible or not.

I guess I need to do something with 'google.maps.event.addListener(markers,'click', function()' but I really have no idea.

Here is my code.

```
<html>
<head>
    .
    .
    .
    <script type='text/javascript' src='...'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='...'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        var ...
        function initialize() {
            var myOptions = {...};
            map = new google.maps.Map(...);
            mgr = new MarkerManager(map);
            google.maps.event.addListener(...);

                markers.setIcon(...);

            google.maps.event.addListener(...);
                var ...
                icons = ...; 
                markers = new google.maps.Marker({...});  
                google.maps.event.addListener(markers,'click', function() {
                    if(clk){
                        markers.infowindow.close(); 
                        clk = false;
                    } 

                    markers.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({...}); 
                    markers.infowindow.open(map, this); clk = true;

                }); 
                mgr.addMarker(markers, 0);
                mgr.refresh();


            });
        }

    </script>
.
.
.
```

In addition, (in case it affects the answer), I use JavaFX and extend application class creates a Browser class and put .html in Browser class.
Thank you all in forward

Comment: Send the data to the server via an AJAX request and handle the response if needed. The Java side normally doesn't need any special treatment besides the mime-type and the response content, which would be JSON or XML instead of HTML. Look at jQuery for an AJAX plugin on the JavaScript side.

Comment: Is it only the way?
Because I have no idea in what you just said
Sorry I'm very newbie programmer and Java is only I asset
(I just learned JavaScript syntax 2 days ago)

Comment: AJAX is probably the simplest and most appropriate way if you do not want a reload of your entire page. If you dont mind reloading, you may just send the variables as HTTP parameters (using HTTP GET or POST).

Comment: Okay, I might try Google both approach and hope I would find the solution soon.
Thanks you two again